# How to open a custom attachment using an Android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, file-extension, intentfilter

I have an attachment with a custom extension (say .abc) whose mimeType I'm unaware of. I would want to open this attachment using my Android application. I tried adding the code below to the manifest but that didn't seem to help. I did go through multiple Stack Overflow posts but none seem to work and those that do also expose my app to other extensions and not just .abc

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern="*.*\\.abc" />
            <data android:host="*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Have you looked at this question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030832/associating-certain-file-extension-to-my-android-application

Answer (score 3):

There's an opening `*` in your `pathPattern`. Any reason for that? It shouldn't be a lead character, since it only affects the preceding character.

From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path):

> - An asterisk ('*') matches a sequence of 0 to many occurrences of the immediately preceding character.
> - A period followed by an asterisk (".*") matches any sequence of 0 to many characters.

You may also want to add an `android:scheme` element. From the same section as above:

> These attributes are meaningful only if the scheme and host attributes are also specified for the filter.

Also, here's a [near duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1733195/752320) you can read through, with a widely accepted answer.

Comment: Hey tnks. The issue is that path pattern applies only for files stored on local storage. Also, unless there is a mimeType specified, it is accessible by other apps as well.

Comment: The path pattern doesn't discriminate between local/remote. Remove the leading `*` and it should match anything ending in ".abc"(unless it has an intermediate `.`, which is an unfortunate implementation of android's `PatternMatcher`). As for "accessible by other apps", I'm not sure what you mean. Are you trying to make it so that your app is the *only* app that can open a certain file type? If so, that won't work. The intent system doesn't work that way.

Comment: The *scheme* used in the other answer is what distinguishes between local and remote, btw.

Comment: I tried to change it to accept ".abc" but it accepts it for ".abc" and ".abc*" for some reason. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried `".*\\.abc"`? The opening `.*` means "any amount of any leading character(s)". The `\\.` is an escaped(literal) `.`, followed by characters `abc`. For more, you should read up on regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `android:scheme`

```
<activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:host="*" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*abc" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.abc" /> <!-- path includes one '.' -->
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.abc" /> <!-- path includes two '.' -->
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.abc" /> <!-- path includes three '.' -->
        <!-- repeat as long as you want -->
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? It's working perfectly in my apps.