# Is it possible to launch app from URL and handle the URL content from inside app?

Tags: android-manifest, desktop, gluon-mobile, info-plist

I want to use a functionality from which the user can launch my app/application from pressing a project file. I have my eyes on the `com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.RuntimeArgsService` Gluon service.

My first step will be to just launch the app from a URL. However - I would like to know if/how it could be possible to let my application know from what URL it was launched - so it can automatically import that project and display it for the user.

**Can the launch URL be provided to the app/application - so it can know from where it was launched?**

Comment: Would it also be possible to make the mobile operating system notify my app if an associated file of the app gets deleted? The iOS "Files" app knows whenever I delete a file in a cloud app, and stays updated... Can I do something similar?

Answer (score 2):

With modification to the, `AndroidManifest.xml` for Android - and `Default-Info.plist`on iOS and by using the `com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.RuntimeArgsService` this was possible.

```
Services.get(RuntimeArgsService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
    service.addListener(LAUNCH_URL_KEY, con -> {
        out("Received LAUNCH_URL_KEY: " + con);
    });
});
```

(The`import static com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.RuntimeArgsService.LAUNCH_URL_KEY` is required)

con here (for Consumer object), contains the url from where the app was launched from. In my case a file named `.example` I made myself. And that lead me to the modification of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file which was also needed:

To the `AndroidManifest.xml` file I added the following:
[image]

In Gluon Charm library: http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.4.0/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/RuntimeArgsService.html - it is explained how to use the service, but tells you to set you scheme as "yourScheme" (not taken literary ofcource).

Here is Android documentation about the type of tags neccassary. It states some are mandatory to give (in order to associate file extensions to your app - among other things). I came upon this post [Cannot open custom file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744539/cannot-open-custom-file-extension). Note that he is setting scheme to "file" which is neccassary.

Remember that some `data` is required add even though you do not set them to anything specific. This all made it work for me to launch my app from the file extension type specified and then recieving the url through the listener by object `con`.

---

On iOS I got this working by adding two keys inside the `Defualt-Info.plist` file. By adding those I am telling the system that my app can open ".exa" (as in example) files. "TryingService" is the name of the Gluon application.
[image]

It is also possible on iOS to recieve url schemes with edits to the `Defualt-Info.plist` file explained here: [How can I open/send a URL to another app on iOS with a Gluon application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064507/how-can-i-open-send-a-url-to-another-app-on-ios-with-a-gluon-application) in the comments to that question.

And on Android it should also be possibel to use `intents` - which is already used by the `ShareService` in Gluon Charm Down library : https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/153d43c06ff129f1ff93cc48a030c3a2cf099281/plugins/plugin-share/android/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/android/AndroidShareService.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default