# How can I open/send a URL to another app on iOS with a Gluon application?

Tags: ios, communication, url-scheme, gluon

I hope to make use of existing functionalities in other apps on iOS in my own app. To my knowledge it should be able to be done with URL custom schemes:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Right now in my `TryingService` gluon application that are acting as a listener, I am using `RuntimeArgsService` to listen for `LAUNCH_URL_KEY`. And to my `Default-Info.plist` file of this application I have added `URL Identifier` : `com.tryingservice.TryingService`, and `URL Scheme`: `outputHello`. How should I set up my "sender" Gluon application - to open the `TryingService` application with the `URL Scheme`?

Right now I am stuck with a functionable URL:
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what is your question: Are you asking how to use `RuntimeArgsService` on iOS? Do you want to open _any_ app in your iOS device from a Gluon app? Or do you want to open a Gluon app from a different app (possibly another Gluon app)?

Comment: Lets say I want to open a Gluon apppplication with another Gluon application. How does Gluon application A launch Gluon application B. That is what I am looking for. (I assume the same can be done with any app though - as long as they have registered a url scheme)

Comment: If you want to open a Gluon app you can use `RuntimeArgsService` and register a custom scheme on it. Then you can include a link with an URL with that scheme in another app, and when the user clicks on that link the former app will be opened. Is this what you want?

Comment: I've tested it from a regular HTML page containing that custom URL in an external browser. Possibly the `BrowserService` could be used to launch that URL as well.

Comment: What is the syntax, if URL Identifier is  `com.tryingservice.TryingService` and URL Scheme is `outputHello`? I followed this to add them to the `Defualt-Info.plist`: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629

Comment: I think you can use `outputHello://<your text here>`, and you will get that full URL in the app with `RuntimeArgsService`.

Comment: Yes that worked. I had mistakenly added 2 listeners, one for `LAUNCH_URL_KEY` and one for "outputHello". After removing the faulty "outputHello" listener and typing it as you said`outputHello://com.tryingservice.TryingService` (in my case), a link was created and the exact same URL was recieved in my `TryingService` Gluon application.

Comment: How can parameters be sent with URL though? I can't "share" (using `ShareService`) to a specific app - with a destination - without having the user to select app to "open with", and I don't know if `java.net.URLConnection` works? Maybe it is required to use native code - following that link of `Inter-App Communication`?.

Comment: So far, the current implementation of `RunArgsService` only checks for a string, so you could create a URL expression, like `outputHello://com.tryingservice.TryingService?param1=val1&param2=val2`, and then parse it properly.

Comment: I forgot about the `consumer.fire(String key, String value)` method inside `RuntimeArgsService`... Should it be possible to put the `outputHello://com.tryingservice.TryingService` as "key", and the content I want to send with "value"?

Comment: Only if you modify and customize the service.

Comment: Alright. The service already uses `openURL` mentioned in the Apples own guide. So it might not be that difficult. However should it not be possible of writing it in java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406518/why-does-javas-url-class-not-recognize-certain-protocols. When initializing `java.net.URL` I get `java.net.MafomedURlExcption`, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363573/registering-and-using-a-custom-java-net-url-protocol I am expecing the url to be functionable. Hopfully the gluon listening application will respond, but it might be required to use native calls to iOS system

Answer (score 1):

In the end I made a custom service implementation to ios by following this example: http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative/

When doing this and after learning some Objective-C I noticed the `BrowserService` which already had been hinted by José Pereda in the comments to the question - the similarity to my own `MyService.m` Objective-C file.

After investigating this futher the check in https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/11c36e187921/plugins/plugin-browser/ios/src/main/native/Browser.m?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default ... `if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:nsUrl])` - makes it unavailable to launch my custom URL Scheme.

By removing that `if`- statement in the `BrowserService` the `BrowserService` can launch another app that has registered a `URL-Scheme`. And it does it without launching safari/default browser can be mentioned.

So here is a Gluon app launching another Gluon app (that listens for `LAUNCH_URL_KEY` with `RuntimeArgsService`) 
[image]

The correct format also given by José was: `outputHello://<your text here>`. So I could both leave it empty or adding (a URL to a file for instance) directly after the `URL-Scheme` part.

However a URL leading to an app's local storage can´t be read from another app due to iOS app Sandbox: [What is Sandbox in ios , Can i Trans data between in one App to Another App in iPhone,if possible how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055990/what-is-sandbox-in-ios-can-i-trans-data-between-in-one-app-to-another-app-in-i)

It should be possible to "open url with options" though as suggested here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopenurloptionskey?language=objc.